# Delay in change notification for channel messages in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-webhooks

We implemented the change notifications subscription for channel messages as per the Microsoft Teams guidelines. We received the messages within 1 minute until 12-July-2021. Now we see a latency of about 2 - 15 minutes for sometimes notably on PST day time.

According to this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#latency) channel messages will be notified within 1 minute.

Could you please let us know what is causing this delay serving the request ?

We would also like to know if there is policy or priority on serving the notifications based on tenant type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How persistent is this latency on your end?

Comment: It didn't exceed 30 sec time when we tried few times on our local? As @Danstan said, is it happening for every time during PST day?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT, Danstan   Latency is intermittent. When compared to last week this week it is good. I will update here when we receive more than 60 seconds delay.

Our Tenant is a Free Trial Tenant (Microsoft 365 E5 Developer (without Windows and Audio Conferencing) Trial) Will that affect the response time ?

Comment: As per the docs, I didn't find anything related to tenant type affects latency.

Comment: I agree with @hunaid-hanfee-msft, there is nothing in the docs around tenant type. Please observe and get back.